# Covid-19 and Original Antigenic Sin

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system

My understanding of original antigenic sin, which I admit is minimal, is that with some pathogens, your immune system gets too focused on one variant and thus is wholly unprepared to deal with a future, similar infection.  Your immune system learns to fight one variant of Covid, and then when facing another variant, it reacts the same way.  But the antibodies for the first variant don't work on the second.

I ask because I recently watched [Geert Vanden Bossche discuss the hypothesis with Bret Weinstein](https://youtu.be/BNyAovuUxro).  I saw him discuss it about a month ago on another channel as well, and he seemed like a crank, but the fact that Bret Weinstein takes him seriously is giving me second thoughts.  I don't want to just take his ideas as gospel, but I also haven't seen anyone debunk what he says.

So have there been any studies about original antigenic sin with regards to Covid-19 and the vaccine?  Does it even make sense consider it?

I'm not an anti-vaxxer loon, I get my flu shot every year and if I ever have kids they'll get their childhood vaccines, please do not just discount me as yet another conspiracy theorist.

Comment: Bossche is a crank. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/98788/is-there-any-plausible-biological-mechanism-for-universally-protective-vaccines

Comment: Weinstein doesn't seem to have any qualifications in the area. "intellectual dark web"... Joe Rogan, etc. As for your actual Q it seem to lack basic prior research a simple query finds https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33692194/ etc.

Comment: @Fizz he's not exactly a nobody either though.  He IS an evolutionary biologist.

Comment: He is a nobody in immunology.

Comment: And based on his more [recent comments](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/jun/16/youtube-videos/no-sign-covid-19-vaccines-spike-protein-toxic-or-c/), Weinstein is at least clueless about terminology in such matters, if not worse.